# Not able to load html within div more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a listener for tab selection changes, and want to be able to load content in a div element, everytime I click on a tab:
However, the following works only for the first time. With subsequent clicks on the tabs, the page (or div region) is blank.

```
tabSelectionHandler = function (event, ui) {
    // .... code to get tab that was clicked
    //..code to get URL
    var nextURL = PAGE_URL[tabName];
    $('#' + tabName + 'Content').load(nextURL, function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {});
}
```

I want the content to be loaded everytime tab is clicked, as the content may be dynamic.. How do I do that?

Comment: i suppose you use jquery tabs?

Comment: I use tabs that are built on top of jquery tabs..

Comment: Do you see an issue with loading an html page more than once within a div element?

Comment: Does it work once for each tab, or it works only once?

Comment: By definition of .load(), the second argument is data to be passed to server not the function. .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] ) Are you using it right?

Answer (score 0):

How I do this is like this:

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">abc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">xyz</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1"></div>
            <div id="tabs-2"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can access each tab like this:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        var active = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");
        var tabId = $("#tabs ul>li a").eq(active).attr('href');
        if (tabId === "#tabs-1") {
           //set url here
           loadHtml(tabId,url );
        } else if (tabId === "#tabs-2") {
            //set url here
            loadHtml(tabId,url );
        } 
    }
});
```

And then have a javaScript function that loads the content:

```
function loadHtml(id,url){
    $('#'+id).html("some html here"); 
    //you can place an ajax call here or whatever is suitable
    //In your case that would be something like
    //$('#' + id).load(url); 
}
```

Hope that helps